# Android: Horizontally scrolling, spanable text not working together

Tags: android

Hello stackoverflow community!

I have a little problem and after searching on Google for days I would like to seek your help.

The goal I want to get to is to have a scrolling text in Android with clickable parts in it. So far so good, the scrolling part is working and the clicking to, but sadly when I click a span of the whole text only the onClick listener that is linked to the first span is called and never the one that is linked to the span that got clicked.

Here is my code so far (C# code because of Xamarin):

```
SpannableStringBuilder scrollingTextBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
foreach(DataStruct detail in dbExchange.DataList)
{
    SpannableStringBuilder singleTextBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(detail.timeSlot + ": " + detail.videoName);
    singleTextBuilder.SetSpan(new SpanClickHelper(detail.videoID), 0, singleTextBuilder.Length(), SpanTypes.ExclusiveExclusive);
    scrollingTextBuilder.Append(singleTextBuilder);
}

TextView scrollingTextView = (TextView) FindViewById(Resource.Id.scrollingTextView);

scrollingTextView.MovementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.Instance;
scrollingTextView.SetText(scrollingTextBuilder, TextView.BufferType.Spannable);
scrollingTextView.StartAnimation((Animation)AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(this, Resource.Animation.scrollAnim));
```

And here the SpanClickHelper class:

```
public class SpanClickHelper : ClickableSpan
{
    private string videoID;

    public SpanClickHelper(string videoID)
    {
        this.videoID = videoID;
    }

    #region implemented abstract members of ClickableSpan

    public override void OnClick(global::Android.Views.View widget)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("clicked: " + videoID);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I hope you know a tip or two to get me on the right track. Hopefully I'm not entirly on the wrong trip.

Comment: did you check if each detail has different detail.videoID?

Comment: @pskink Yes, they all have different values

Comment: instead of WriteLining videoID try to WriteLine HashCode()

Comment: @pskink Same result, the hashcode is every click the same when I click on another textspan in the whole scrolling text.

Comment: maybe try using one SpannableStringBuilder instead of appending temporary SpannableStringBuilders

Comment: @pskink I tried that before but apart from making the code look more complicated it didn't changed anything.

Comment: i dont know why but in java it works just fine, maybe SpanTypes is a root of problem, in java its Spanned iface

Comment: @pskink Do you have your code sample in Java? Would like to compare it :)

Answer (score 0):

try this (put it in onCreate() method)

```
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setTextSize(32);
tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
SpannableStringBuilder b = new SpannableStringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    String link = "#" + i;
    SpannableStringBuilder tmp = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    tmp.append("link " + link);
    ClickableSpan span = new CS(link);
    tmp.setSpan(span, 0, tmp.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    tmp.append("\n\n\n");
    b.append(tmp);
}
tv.setText(b);
sv.addView(tv);

setContentView(sv);

Printer printer = new LogPrinter(Log.DEBUG, TAG);
TextUtils.dumpSpans(b, printer, "spans: ");
```

class CS looks like:

```
class CS extends ClickableSpan {
    private String s;

    public CS(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick " + s);
    }
}
```

for flags == Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE in setSpan() i got (note the ranges before fl=...):

```
D/Main    (  386): spans: link #0: 43dccd60 org.pskink.pathdrawable.Main.CS (0-7) fl=#33
D/Main    (  386): spans: link #1: 43dcd138 org.pskink.pathdrawable.Main.CS (10-17) fl=#33
D/Main    (  386): spans: link #2: 43dcd468 org.pskink.pathdrawable.Main.CS (20-27) fl=#33
D/Main    (  386): spans: link #3: 43dcd780 org.pskink.pathdrawable.Main.CS (30-37) fl=#33
D/Main    (  386): spans: link #4: 43dcda10 org.pskink.pathdrawable.Main.CS (40-47) fl=#33
```

for flags == Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE (i removed lots of output here since all the spans
extend to the end of buffer, see *-50 below) you can see that link #0 has the range 0-50 and 
this span intercepts all clicks:

```
D/Main    (  470): spans: link #0 [cut] : 43dccd60 org.pskink.pathdrawable.Main.CS (0-50) fl=#18
D/Main    (  470): spans: link #1 [cut] : 43dcd138 org.pskink.pathdrawable.Main.CS (10-50) fl=#18
D/Main    (  470): spans: link #2 [cut] : 43dcd468 org.pskink.pathdrawable.Main.CS (20-50) fl=#18
D/Main    (  470): spans: link #3 [cut] : 43dcd780 org.pskink.pathdrawable.Main.CS (30-50) fl=#18
D/Main    (  470): spans: link #4 [cut] : 43dcda10 org.pskink.pathdrawable.Main.CS (40-50) fl=#18
```

Comment: Thanks for your code sample. Sadly I can't get it to work on my side. Maybe the problem is that the TextView is in a HorizontalView, because the text is longer than the phone width, and thats making problems? When I change the flags to SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE, the whole text is highlighted when I click it but with SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE only the first span is highlighted, even when I click another part.

Comment: all right, forget my previous comment and try first to convert my java code to C# and see if it works

Comment: I converted your java code into C# and its working. So I put your last two lines from onCreate into my project and this is the output:

`[TAG] spans: [...] SpanClickHelper (0-69) fl=#33
[TAG] spans: [...] SpanClickHelper (80-147) fl=#33
[TAG] spans: [...] SpanClickHelper (158-238) fl=#33
[TAG] spans: [...] SpanClickHelper (249-321) fl=#33
[TAG] spans: [...] SpanClickHelper (332-418) fl=#33`

Everything looks ok. But I think the difference between yours and mine is my automatic horizontal scrolling. Maybe this is messing something up with the HorizontalView...

Comment: how does your horiz scrolling look like? btw try to replace ScrollView with HorizontalScrollView and remove "\n"s  from SSB

Comment: Finally, I tracked down the problem! Thanks pskink so far for your help. The root of the problem is the automatic scroll animation. When I disable it all works fine. This is the code for the animation:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="50000"
    android:fromXDelta="15%p"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:toXDelta="-99%p" />`
To you have a idea how to solve this?

Comment: use a Handler +postDelayed + scrollTo

Comment: I looked into it but I cannot find a way to make a scrolling text that runs again when one whole scroll is finished with this method.